# Will it be fast if I use amazon web services for India?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My portal will be mainly accessed in India and it involves uploading/viewing of images which means good data transfer will be involved.

If I host my portal on servers located in India; surely it will be faster to access the pages.  But I want to personally use Amazon web services. Do we have option in Amazon so that we can host our tomcat server and save images on some servers located in India ; or at max. in Singapore so that access is fairly faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) offers several *AWS datacenter Regions* for most of their [Products & Services](http://aws.amazon.com/products/) within their *steadily expanding global infrastructure*, amongst those the *Asia Pacific (Singapore) Region* (usually referred to as `ap-southeast-1`).

Furthermore they do offer even more so called edge locations for [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), which is their [Content delivery network (CDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) alike *web service for content delivery*.

You can see an overview of the current regions and edge locations on their [Global Infrastructure](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/globalinfrastructure/) map.

There is an API oriented [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) listing as well, see e.g. those for the [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region) (please note that not every region does necessarily support every single available product, especially beta offerings are usually available in `us-east-1` only initially).

Consequently you should be fine using `ap-southeast-1` for your use case, though as usual you might want to give it a try before settling on this, which is fairly easy to do by means of the [AWS Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) offering.